# Most efficient way to replace one sequence of the bytes with some other sequence

Tags: c#, arrays

What is the most efficient way to replace one sequence of the bytes (eg 67 67 67) with some other sequence of the bytes (eg 90). 
The sequences can have different length.

Comment: [What did you try](http://whatdidyoutry.com)?

Comment: And what kind of NOT nice solutions you found?

Comment: If you know they are letters, can't you make a string and use its replace method?

Comment: From what I understand the question is how to replace one sequence of the bytes (eg 67 67 67) with some other sequence of the bytes (eg 90). The sequences can have different length. It's not about simple chars replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short app which does what you need:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte [] bArray = new byte[] {11, 67, 67, 67, 33, 34, 67, 67, 11, 33, 67, 67, 67, 67};

        byte[] result = Replace(bArray, new byte[] {67, 67, 67}, new byte[] {90});

        foreach (byte b in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }

    private static byte [] Replace(byte[] input, byte[] pattern, byte[] replacement)
    {
        if (pattern.Length == 0)
        {
            return input;
        }

        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= input.Length - pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            bool foundMatch = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
            {
                if (input[i + j] != pattern[j])
                {
                    foundMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (foundMatch)
            {
                result.AddRange(replacement);
                i += pattern.Length - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(input[i]);
            }
        }

        for (; i < input.Length; i++ )
        {
            result.Add(input[i]);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```