# How to edit hex code in a file? Regex corrupts the file

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I am trying to edit the hex code of a file. The code in C# needs to find either the decoded text i.e., `1004` or the corresponding hex `31 30 30 34` and replace with string `2113` or either the corresponding hex `32 31 31 33`

I have tried to edit the string directly using:-

```
string test = File.ReadAllText("tram.png");
Regex id = new Regex("1004");
string idre = id.Replace(test, "2113", 1);
File.WriteAllText("tram.png", idre);
```

Also tried `Byte` method

```
Byte[] test = File.ReadAllBytes("tram.png");             
Byte[] id = new Regex("1004");             
Byte[] idre = id.Replace(test, "2113", 1);
File.WriteAllBytes("tram.png", idre);
```

It says 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Replace' and Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' to 'byte[]'

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: PNG is not a text file. You need to read the file bytes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yah, I also tried with other text files. But, it just doesn't work. I am still not able to figure out the byte method though. I tried 
            `Byte[] test = File.ReadAllBytes("tram.png");
            Byte[] id = new Regex("1004");
            Byte[] idre = id.Replace(test, "2113", 1);
            File.WriteAllBytes("tram.png", idre);`

And, it gives me an error that Bye doesn'thave replace defined.

Comment: The `Replace` methods work on strings not bytes. You need to use a different scheme. Please [edit] the question to explain the problem more clearly and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Sure, regex only works on text data. You need to convert byte to strings, run the regex and then convert back.

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllBytes`, then [replace the appropriate bytes in that byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132890/c-sharp-replace-bytes-in-byte), then use `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Tried the two methods in the question. I have updated it.

Comment: @JoeSewell I tried that and when I try to add the extension method as in the answer,it just gives me extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class. Tried adding static, tried adding under namespace created a namespace, etc., but none work. The hex replace has to take place as part of a button click event.

Comment: Then make sure you understand what an extension method is. Similarly, with the second way you posted in your question, you said you were getting errors because `Byte[]` doesn't have a `Replace` method and `Regex` cannot be assigned to a `Byte[]` variable. You should read up on these topics to have a better understanding of C#, for this and future questions you come across. Ex: [Extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), [Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/)

Comment: You may end up corrupting the file if you do this - firstly there is a chance that your sequence of bytes could naturally occur in a binary file (1 in 2^32 chance is small but not zero). Secondly, I believe in a  PNG file data blocks have CRC check codes in them which will no longer match if you start editing bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use regex on bytes. You can look for the pattern manually and just replace those elements in the array:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("tram.png");

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 4; ++i)
{
    if (bytes[i] == 31 && bytes[i + 1] == 30 && bytes[i + 2] == 30 && bytes[i + 3] == 34)
    {
        bytes[i] = 32;
        bytes[i + 1] = 31;
        bytes[i + 2] = 31;
        bytes[i + 3] = 33;

        i += 3;  // Skip the new bytes for efficiency.
    }
}

File.WriteAllBytes("tram.png", bytes);
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it says Invalid real literal if the code had a letter in it, like `2E`

Comment: @droidtaber If you want to use hex instead of decimal, you have to prefix it with `0x`, (e.g. `0x2E`).

Comment: This worked! But, there's a small issue. I was running `id.Replace(test, "2113", 1);` cause there are two instances of the same hex in the document. Anyway to limit to first instance?

Comment: @droidtaber Yes, just replace the `i += 3;` line with `break;`.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Have been trying to fix this for more than a day now. BTW, in the above code, it should be `bytes` with the example instead of `test`.
Have a nice day! Thanks a lot again.